# Helm - Templating variables in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, templating

I'm trying to template variables from a map inside the values.yaml into my final Kubernetes ConfigMap YAML.

I've read through https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492 and https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/ but can't seem to find an answer.

For some context, this is roughly what I'm trying to do:

**values.yaml**

```
config:
  key1: value
  key2: value-{{ .Release.Name }}
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  config-file: |
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.config }}
    {{ $key }} = {{ $value }}
    {{- end }}
```

Where the desired output with would be:

**helm template --name v1 mychart/**

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  config-file: |
    key1 = value
    key2 = value-v1
```

I've tried a few variations using template functions and pipelining, but to no avail:

```
{{ $key }} = {{ tpl $value . }}
{{ $key }} = {{ $value | tpl . }}
{{ $key }} = {{ tpl $value $ }}
```

Answer (score 32):

I'll refer to the question's title regarding templating variables in helm and suggest another option to use on `values.yaml` which is YAML Anchors.

#### Docs reference

As written in [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors):

The YAML spec provides a way to store a reference to a value, and
later refer to that value by reference. YAML refers to this as
"anchoring":

```
coffee: "yes, please"
favorite: &favoriteCoffee "Cappucino"
coffees:
  - Latte
  - *favoriteCoffee
  - Espresso
```

In the above, `&favoriteCoffee` sets a reference to *Cappuccino*.

Later, that reference is used as `*favoriteCoffee`.
So coffees becomes *Latte*, *Cappuccino*, *Espresso*.

#### A more practical example

Referring to a common image setup (`Registry` and `PullPolicy`) in all `values.yaml`.

Notice how the default values are being set at `Global.Image` next to the reference definition which starts with `&`:

```
Global:
  Image:
    Registry: &global-docker-registry "12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" # <--- Default value
    PullPolicy: &global-pull-policy "IfNotPresent" # <--- Default value

Nginx:
  Image:
    Registry: *global-docker-registry
    PullPolicy: *global-pull-policy
    Version: 1.21.4
    Port: 80

MySql:
  Image:
    Registry: *global-docker-registry
    PullPolicy: *global-pull-policy
    Name: mysql
    Version: 8.0.27
    Port: 3306
```

Comment: how to use this approach if I want to use this variable as a part in some value like

MySql:
  Image:
    Registry: Prefix-*global-docker-registry-Suffix

Comment: I haven't tried string concatenation in the values file - not sure it would work. You can add the prefix/suffux in the resource itself, and let the *global-docker-registry injected from the global reference.

Comment: that has a very limited use-case due to how helm anchors work. https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors :

if you override Global.Image.Registry with --set all your references will remain with the original value of the anchor. which is nasty

Answer (score 31):

The above would also have worked in this way

**values.yaml**

```
config:
  key1: "value"
  key2: "value-{{ .Release.Name }}"
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  config-file: |
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.config }}
    {{ $key }} = {{ tpl $value $ }}
    {{- end }}
```

What I changed was : I put value in quotes in `value.yaml` and used template `tpl` in the config map.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering: When the `tpl` function is used in a range block, it needs the top-level context (e.g. `$`) as the second argument instead of the usual `.` argument. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815474/392184

Answer (score 16):

Managed to solve this using the following syntax:

**configmap.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  config-file: |
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.config }}
    {{ $key }} = {{ tpl ($value | toString) $ }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: it could be nice to mark as answer your answer or https://stackoverflow.com/a/62896363/3102264

Comment: Yeah... the author of a question should always mark the solution, so that others _know for sure_ what worked in your case. :-)

Answer (score 11):

there is fight [in this PR here](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/6876) about this topic.

I know that it's possible now, but this require maintenance of the chart to be in-house (e.g. answer of Amrut ).

Let's summarize :

To have templating in `values.yaml` , these are the available options:

1. helm may support that in future ( watch this [thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/6876) about this topic.)
2. use tpl function inside the chart
3. use another tool on top of helm : terraform or helmfile.

Comment: Saw the github thread, would be helpful if that has been implemented. I see the changes are merged. Are the changes available officially?