# How to call one variable into another in value.yaml of helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How to call one variable to another in value.yaml of a chart?
for example, this is the value.yaml

```
app: "test"
count: 1
frontend:
  image: "mydockerhub/$app"
  replicaCount: $count
backend:
  image: "mydockerhub/backend"
  replicaCount: $count
```

Here one line 1 and 2. I am assigning values to `app` and `count`. Now I want to use this variable in defining frontend image and replicacount.

I know I can directly update the variables in values.yaml but the original values.yaml is quite big and complicated.

P.S I am trying to access a parameter's value into another in Value.yaml itself, not any configmap or any other file.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958507/helm-templating-variables-in-values-yaml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm - Templating variables in values.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958507/helm-templating-variables-in-values-yaml)

Comment: @DavidMaze: Nope. That's totally different thing. I am trying to call one variable's value into another variable in value.yaml only. I guess Rafal is right. I can't use parameters from values.yaml inside values.yaml

Answer (score 3):

Can't YAML Anchors be the solution?
See https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/

It would give something like this:

```
app: "test"
count: &appCount 1
frontend:
  image: "mydockerhub/$app"
  replicaCount: *appCount
backend:
  image: "mydockerhub/backend"
  replicaCount: *appCount
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use parameters from `values.yaml` inside `values.yaml`, since the values file is not evaluated.

Comment: I guess you are right. I'll wait for some more time then I'll accept your answer

Comment: Hi @VikasRathore Were you able to find solution for this? Even I'm struck with similar problem as yours..

Comment: @Sudhanvac: There is no such option