# Helm tpl function to render a file does not work

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to render a file using the tpl function. I am retrieving the content of the file using Files.Get, which works fine until I use tpl function on it.

My input file is:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
```

My helm template is:

```
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- tpl ($files.Get "files/autoscaling.yaml" ) . -}}
```

I had to use $files because it would throw the error:

> at <.Files.Get>: can't evaluate field Files in type interface {}

The output that I see when I run the helm template is

```
Error: template: subchart-demoapp/templates/sub-deployments.yaml:5:47: executing "subchart-demoapp/templates/sub-deployments.yaml" at <.>: wrong type for value; expected chartutil.Values; got string
helm.go:84: [debug] template: subchart-demoapp/templates/sub-deployments.yaml:5:47: executing "subchart-demoapp/templates/sub-deployments.yaml" at <.>: wrong type for value; expected chartutil.Values; got string
```

My helm version is:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.1", GitCommit:"fe51cd1e31e6a202cba7dead9552a6d418ded79a", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.10"}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out. `tpl` function when used in a `range` block needs the top-level context as the second argument. Ref: [Helm Issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5979)

Replaced the `.` with `$` and it works as expected.