# use {{range}} in .Values to generate a list

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm

In helm I have the following .Values

```
mqtt:
  topics:
    - /tenant/+/#
    - /otherStuff/
    - /importantStuff/

tenants:
  - id: tenantA
    name: Tenant A
  - id: tenantB
    name: Tenant B
```

Instead of the wildcard topic `/tenant/+/#` I reather would like to have the topics tenant specific:

- `/tenant/tenantA/#`
- `/tenant/tenantB/#`

So I tried what would make sense to me should work:

```
mqtt:
  topics:
{{- range .Values.tenants }}
    - /tenant/{{ .id }}/#
{{ end }}
    - /otherStuff/
    - /importantStuff/
```

This leads to multiple errors

```
A block sequence may not be used as an implicit map key
Implicit keys need to be on a single line
Implicit map keys need to be followed by map values
```

While not completly understanding the errors, it seems to me that this approach does not work or I am doing something completely wrong.

How can I loop in my .Values over a range and generate to generate a list?

[Helm Playground](https://helm-playground.com/#t=LQhQFMA8EMFsAcA24BcACA3h4aB0A1aRAV3AGddYBHAFxtxoHt4BLAYzIF9PQg&v=LYRwLmBcBQAEtgPYAcCWBjAzjA3jgtLAE4CGAdgOYCmsAdAGokA2ArlZrWFWeWJrAF8BceLEIB6LjzJhxeOqgAmggeIDE0ed2VCR8CYjAALKkQDKYFgDMr4vWNjjUwZIiJheF67ejQpvbBFCJUgEbl4AQXseYCpQgBVwmVgo-VgQsOkwACFokliEpLBYbKA) (Actually shows a different error as visual studio code does, but probably the same lead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm doesn't allow this.  The contents of `values.yaml` must be a flat YAML file, and no templating is applied to it.

[Helm - Templating variables in values.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958507/helm-templating-variables-in-values-yaml) addresses a simpler case of this for simple strings using the Helm [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function to render a string.  You could do that here, but it's trickier: the `values.yaml` value must be a string, and you'll have to ask Helm to parse the result of `tpl` with `fromYaml`.

```yaml
# values.yaml
mqtt:
  #       v YAML "block scalar" marker to create a multiline string
  topics: |
    {{- range .Values.tenants }}
    - /tenant/{{ .id }}/#
    {{ end }}
    - /otherStuff/
    - /importantStuff/
#^^^ also note all contents are indented
```

```
{{- $topics := tpl .Values.mqtt.topics . | fromYaml }}
{{- range $topic := $topics }}...{{ end }}
```

Comment: I use [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/) for some multi-chart scenarios.  It's notable here because it _does_ allow applying a `values.yaml.gotmpl` file; this also gets confusing because Helmfile has its own notion of `.Values` that are used to render the file that will become `.Values` when the chart is installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#controlling-whitespace)

> The curly brace syntax of template declarations can be modified with special characters to tell the template engine to chomp whitespace. `{{-` (with the dash and space added) indicates that whitespace should be chomped left, while `-}}` means whitespace to the right should be consumed. Be careful! Newlines are whitespace!

```yaml
mqtt: 
  topics:
    {{- range .Values.tenants }}
    - /tenant/{{ .id }}/#
    {{- end }}
    - /otherStuff/
    - /importantStuff/
```

values.yaml

```yaml
tenants:
  - id: tenantA
    name: Tenant A
  - id: tenantB
    name: Tenant B
```

output

```yaml
mqtt: 
  topics:
    - /tenant/tenantA/#
    - /tenant/tenantB/#
    - /otherStuff/
    - /importantStuff/
```

---

[image: helm-playground]

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this doesn't change anything. I still get the same errors. I added a link of a online playground.

Comment: I also tried it in helm-playground and got the expected result