# Nested Variable Interpolation in Values File

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In a values file I am having some issues with variable expansion and interpolation.
We’ve defined a variable at the top of our values file like:

`webserverInternalIngressHost: 'service.{{ .Values.global.namespace }}.{{ .Values.global.domain }}'`

It is then used like:

```
deployments:
  webserver:
    ingress:
      internal:
        tls:
          - secretName: .......
            hosts:
              - '{{ .Values.webserverInternalIngressHost }}'
```

This does not get interpolated though, and the resultant template is:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "service.{{ .Values.global.namespace }}.{{ .Values.global.domain }}" # <<< Variables not expanded
      secretName: .....
```

If we use `'service.{{ .Values.global.namespace }}.{{ .Values.global.domain }}'` inline like:

```
deployments:
  webserver:
    ingress:
      internal:
        tls:
          - secretName: .......
            hosts:
              - 'service.{{ .Values.global.namespace }}.{{ .Values.global.domain }}'
```

then the output is as expected:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "service.namespace.domain.us" <<< Variables expanded
      secretName: ......
```

Is there anything I can do to dynamically ensure this "nested" variable in interpolated?

Comment: (You had initially tagged this with [tag:helmfile], though you don't seem to be using [that tool](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io).  If you are, then you could use Helm-style `{{ .Values... }}` expressions in a `values:` block in the `helmfile.yaml`, or in an included `values.yaml.gotmpl` file, but note that it's a higher-level Helmfile-global values object and not the per-chart settings.)

Comment: Not sure who closed this, this is not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958507/helm-templating-variables-in-values-yaml which I came across and which clearly has a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with:

```
webserverInternalIngressHost: service.{{ .Values.global.namespace }}.{{ .Values.global.domain }}

deployments:
  webserver:
    ingress:
      internal:
        tls:
          - secretName: .......
            hosts:
              - '{{ tpl .Values.webserverInternalIngressHost . }}'
```